# custom OAuth scopes in azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

Reading through this : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3 trying to understand scopes. According to the spec,  scopes are defined in the auth server but need not to be tied to a single application(I am inferring). When I work with Azure, custom scopes seems to be tied to an app registration (My API ). Is this the case or am I missing something? Is there a way to define scopes that isn't tied to an App (or more than one app).

For example, Directory.Read.All scope, I can imagine more than one API hosted behind a resource server implement all Directory services in graph (not one?)

scope is a vague concept to me so my apologies if my question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I work with Azure, custom scopes seems to be tied to an app
> registration (My API ). Is this the case or am I missing something? Is
> there a way to define scopes that isn't tied to an App (or more than
> one app).

When you get the token, you must specify the `scope` value. Just like you think, your custom scope is actually that you expose the application protected by Azure. Usually it is used as a back-end application. When you use the front-end application to access it, you must specify the scope of the back-end application.  It is usually: `api://{back-end app client api}/scope name`

[image]

> Directory.Read.All scope, I can imagine more than one API hosted
> behind a resource server implement all Directory services in graph
> (not one?)

No, it's not like you think. You should put the api you want to access in the scope. For example, if you want to access MS graph api, you can put `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. If you want to access a custom api, you can put in `api://{back-end app client api}/scope name`.

The access token is issued according to the api **audience** you want to access, it is unique!  see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims).

[image]

Comment: Following up on this question, This spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) says "In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-
   sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value." Looking at azure docs aud is a singular string or uri ? (api id? of the api ) . Is there no way to ask for multiple scopes belonging to two different APIs (end result being multiple scopes and two audiences)?